# What is causing "The Remote Java Bridge has not been attached yet" when attempting to run a polybase query in linux mssql server 2019?

Tags: sql-server, linux, polybase, sql-server-2019

On a Centos 7 vm, we installed mssql server 2019 following the instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-red-hat?view=sql-server-linux-ver15

We then installed mssql-server-polybase following the instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/polybase/polybase-linux-setup?view=sql-server-ver15

After running a query against polybase, we received the following error message:

```
Msg 110813, Level 16, State 1, Line 26
The Remote Java Bridge has not been attached yet.
```

This is the query we attempted to run:

```
use testdb
GO
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE [HadoopSouthMLI] WITH (TYPE = HADOOP, LOCATION = N'hdfs://servername:8020', RESOURCE_MANAGER_LOCATION = N'rm-servername:8032')
GO
CREATE EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT [parquetz_gz_file_format] WITH (FORMAT_TYPE = PARQUET, DATA_COMPRESSION = N'org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec')
GO

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [dbo].[test] (  
        [primary_key] nvarchar(64) NOT NULL,   
        [type] nvarchar(64) NOT NULL,   
        [track_key] nvarchar(64) NOT NULL,   
        [id_number] nvarchar(6),   
        [additional_id_number] nvarchar(6),
                                [score] float NULL,
                                [id] nvarchar(7),

)  
WITH (LOCATION='/path/to/file/',   
        DATA_SOURCE = HadoopSouthMLI,  
        FILE_FORMAT = parquetz_gz_file_format  
);
GO
```

The query works without issues on windows machines that have had mssql-server 2017 installed on them, so I don't believe there is a problem with the query itself.

After receiving the error above I listed the other mssql-server packages available and found a mssql-server-polybase-hadoop package, which also installed two other packages; mssql-zulu-jre-11 and mssql-zulu-jre-8. We installed the package and restarted mssql-server, however, we are still receiving "The Remote Java Bridge has not been attached yet" when attempting the connection.

Are there any additional packages or configuration that are needed to get the bridge created so this query will work?

Comment: *"On a Centos 7 vm, we installed mssql server 2019 following the instructions here:"* But CentOS isn't a supported OS for SQL Server on Linux; there are no instructions there on how to install it on Centos 7, because it's not recommended.

Comment: Edited the post with the correct link to the mssql-server install instructions. Mssql is supported on Centos/RedHat.

Comment: Red Hat isn't Centos, though they are similar. The [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-faq) notes this: *"SQL Server is tested and supported on Linux for the previously listed distributions. Other Linux distributions are closely related and might be able to run SQL Server (for example, CentOS is closely related to Red Hat Enterprise Server). But if you choose to install SQL Server on an unsupported operating system, please review the Support policy section of the Technical support policy for Microsoft SQL Server to understand the support implications."*

Comment: The packages installed without any indication of issues and the services started without any issues. Are there any suggestions on what to check out there other than moving to RedHat? That is not an option for us.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I am having the same issue on Ubuntu 20.04 in docker.